# The element is implicitly of type "any" because an expression of type "string" cannot be used - typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm getting this error when trying to convert my input data into the structure i need, but i don't see any typings errors.

```
 The element is implicitly of type "any" because an expression of type "string" cannot be used to index the type "DocsInfo".
  No index signature found in type "DocsInfo" with parameter of type "string".ts(7053)
```

my code

```
type DocsInfo = {
    title: string;
    active?: number[];
    progress?: number[];
    closed?: number[];
};

const dict: Record<string, string> = {
        active: 'Is Active',
        progress: 'In Progress',
        closed: 'Is Closed',
};

const mappedArray = (arr: number[]) =>
    arr.map((item) => ({ key: String(item), content: item }));


const transformedArray = (data: DocsInfo) => {
        return Object.keys(data).filter((key) => key !== 'title')
            .map(key => ({
                label: dict[key], 
                options: mappedArray(data[key]) // The element is implicitly of type "any" because an expression of type "string" cannot be used to index the type "DocsInfo".
  No index signature found in type "DocsInfo" with parameter of type "string".ts(7053),
            })
    )};
```

my input data is

```
const data: DocsInfo = {
    active: [1, 2, 3],
    closed: [11, 22],
    progress: [111],
    title: '',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the label and options with this:

label: dict[key as keyof DocsInfo],
options: mappedArray(data[key as keyof DocsInfo])

This shoul work

Comment: no, it doesn't work. here `options: mappedArray(data[key as keyof DocsInfo])` i got error now `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'DocsInfo'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'DocsInfo'.`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that you were using `Record<string, string>` to type the dict object, whereas it should be `Record<"active" | "progress" | "closed", string>`, so a type helper `type keys = keyof Omit<DocsInfo, "title">` does the job.

Also, when we do `Object.keys(data)`, typescript implicitly assigns `string[]`, so we need to type cast the array as `Object.keys(data) as (keyof typeof dict)[]`.

```js
type DocsInfo = {
  title: string;
  active ? : number[];
  progress ? : number[];
  closed ? : number[];
};

type keys = keyof Omit < DocsInfo, "title" >

  const dict: Record < keys, string > = {
    active: 'Is Active',
    progress: 'In Progress',
    closed: 'Is Closed',
  };

const mappedArray = (arr: number[]) =>
  arr.map((item) => ({
    key: String(item),
    content: item
  }));


const transformedArray = (data: DocsInfo) => {
  const arr = Object.keys(data) as(keyof typeof dict)[]

  return arr.filter((key) => key in dict)
    .map((key) => ({
      label: dict[key],
      options: mappedArray(data[key] ? ? [])
    }))
};
```

Comment: but after this fixes I still get this error

Comment: Yeah. it was not a proper solution. But I tried to fix it in my code editor, the above solution should work.